# Don't receive a response from sr1 function of scapy. How to specify the timeout parameter? [Python]

Tags: python, networking, tcp, scapy, packet

I am trying to establish a 3-way handshake connection using Scapy with all the device on my network. However, there is a device that does not respond to a SYN packet and my program is stuck. I am using Wireshark for inspection of packets, and nothing comes back.
Is there any way that can overcome this issue? similar to a timeout parameter of `sr()` function.

I've create a syn packet like this:

```py
pkt = sr1(IP(dst=destinationIP)/TCP(dport=destinationPort, flags='S', seq=sequenceNum, ack =acknowledgeNum))
```

Then i am checking the responses with an if statement:

```py
if pkt[TCP].flags == 18: #for SYNACK
    then do something
else:
    close connection
```

For all the devices of the network, the program works fine. However, there is one device that does not respond, but I don't care about it. All I want is to be able to capture somehow that there is no response from `sr1` function and send a packet to the next device.
`sr1()` function does not have a timeout parameter. What i tried to do was something like:

```py
if pkt is None:
    continue
```

But it does not work as well.

Answer (score 2):

`sr1` does have a timeout parameter, this worked for me-

```
pkt = sr1(IP(dst="192.168.1.20")/TCP(dport=1340, flags='S', seq=0, ack =0), timeout=2)
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
.......................................................................
Received 71 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

You can take a look on the triple handshake process in [here](https://gist.github.com/N0dr4x/ffe99618a738978605719ce525a33042) if you need some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was receiving an error when I was trying to specify the timeout parameter. but I double-checked it and found out that is working properly.
My bad. thanks for the help anyway